# Interpolation of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ on Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have used Chebyshev nodes to avoid Runge's phenomenon

```
x = −5 : 0.001 : 5; 
i = 0 : 10; 
xc = −1/2 ∗ 10∗cos((2 ∗ i + 1)/(2 ∗ 10 + 2) ∗ pi);
yc = 1./(1 + xc.ˆ2);
pc = polyfit(xc, yc, length(xc) − 1);
pyc = polyval(pc, x);
plot(x, pyc,'k')
```

This code works fine:[image: output 1]

But:

```
x = −5 : 0.001 : 5;
i = 0 : 50;
xc = −1/2 ∗ 10∗cos((2 ∗ i + 1)/(2 ∗ 10 + 2) ∗ pi);
yc = 1./(1 + xc.ˆ2);
pc = polyfit(xc, yc, length(xc) − 1);
pyc = polyval(pc, x);
plot(x, pyc,'k')
```

[image: output 2]

What is the problem in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: The two codes are exactly the same, and that's ironic

Comment: I thought that too, wondered if I was just going mad from tiredness, but apparently not!

Comment: @polfosol @ lioness99a Sorry, in the first code , there is the line "i = 0 : 10; ", in the second code, there is the line "i = 0 : 50;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    N = 50;
    x = -5 : 0.001 : 5;
    y = 1./(1 + x.^2);
    p = polyfit(x, y, N-1 );
    yp = polyval(p, x); 
    i = 0 : N;
    xc = -1/2 * 10*cos((2 * i + 1)/(2 * N + 2) * pi); % changed
    yc = 1./(1 + xc.^2);
    pc = polyfit(xc, yc, N-1);
    pyc = polyval(pc, x);
    figure
        plot(x, pyc,'b', x, yp, 'r', xc, yc, '.k' )
        grid
```

Note the change in the line that starts with `xc =`. With MATLAB, I get this warning when `N>14`:

```
Warning: Polynomial is badly conditioned. Add points with distinct X values, reduce the
degree of the polynomial, or try centering and scaling as described in HELP POLYFIT.
```